# Updating DBML in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2015, dbml

Up to know I've used [Huagati DBML/EDMX Tools](https://huagati.com/dbmltools/), but it's not working in VS 2015.

How can I update dbml automatically not by drag and drop tables/views again?

Comment: Ask them when they expect to support it.

Comment: @GertArnold, I've already asked, creator of huagati said "No, I won't update it".